# WSL missing method for Golang time.Time

Tags: linux, go, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been working on a cli tool in Go when I ran into this issue. The tool compiles and works perfectly fine when I use the Windows Command Prompt or PowerShell to run it but when I try using WSL (Ubuntu version 1) I get this error message.

`time.Now().UnixMilli undefined (type time.Time has no field or method UnixMilli)`

The file using `time.Now().UnixMilli()` has the package time included `import(..."time"...)` and it is not redefined elsewhere because the code compiles and runs correctly in the Windows terminals. Because of this I assume that it has something to do with Linux for Windows.

I have tried updating the `$GOROOT` and `$GOPATH` to various different places including trying to connect to go installed on the mounted Windows system `/mnt/c/` (this gives a different error of not knowing how compile which makes sense since it's the Windows version of go). I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling various versions of Go for Ubuntu using both `apt-get` and `tar`.

I'm not sure why it isn't working correctly and would love any insight that anyone else might have.

Thanks!

**go env (windows-cmd):**

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\<user>\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\<user>\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.17.3
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Firmware\Git\<project>\cli\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2245089512=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

**go env (wsl-ubuntu):**

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/<user>/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/<user>/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/<user>/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.13"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.13/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/mnt/c/Users/<user>/Documents/Firmware/Git/<project>/cli/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build414455523=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: In the WSL env I see "go-1.13" mentioned, and [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMilli) say UnixMilli was introduced in 1.17 (the version I see on the Windows side). Try installing Go 1.17 in WSL.

Answer (score 4):

The version of go you are running in WSL is 1.13, but `UnixMilli` was only introduced recently in go version 1.17.

If you wish to install multiple versions of go see: https://go.dev/doc/manage-install

Else: https://go.dev/doc/install

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!